# KitKat vs Lollipop transparent status bar

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, coordinator-layout

I use new Android Design Support Library. I have to do scrollable and collapsable header in my app. If I use Lollipop, all is ok. But I can't do it in the KitKat

this looks like I need

[image]

KitKat

[image]

If I add fitsSystemWindows="true" to the root layout (Coordinator) and others, I got results:

(I'm sorry but I don`t have enough rating to post images and link)

- android 5 has white zone below the AppBarLayout

[image]

- KitKat has not overlapped status bar but this is ugly.

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    ...
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Also I'm using Translucent statusBar.
May you help me?

Answer (score 0):

its default Android OS theme you can not override in KITKAT,

what ever is showing in android 5.0 and 4.4.4(KITKAT) both are correct as per style and theme of different OS version.

**in sort android support library not provide that future for lower version of Android OS**

Comment: isnt this answer helpfull. @user3844613